# How can I avoid duplicating code while creating separate vectors from dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to create the vectors from the values present in the row of dataframe. For example-

Dataframe structure as follows-

```
    Item     Category
[1] Apple    Fruit
[2] Onion    Vegetable
[3] Potato   Vegetable
[4] Grapes   Fruit
[5] Cabbage  Vegetable
[6] Orange   Fruit
[7] Peach    Fruit
```

I need two vectors based on item from the same as output grouped by category-

```
Fruits
[1] "Apple"
[2] "Grapes"
[3] "Orange"
[4] "Peach"

Vegetable
[1] "Onion"
[2] "Potato"
[3] "Cabbage"
```

I tried to filter them by Category

```
Vegie <- df %>% 
  filter(Category == "Vegetable")
```

and then creating vector for the same

```
Vegie <- as.vector(Vegie$Item)
```

This works, but I need to repeat this for twice in this example.

In real scenario, I have 17 different categories with same structure, so, it will be time consuming and not so clean. Is there any clean way to do the same? Please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `split(df$Item, df$Category)` will do it - giving you a list of the two vectors.

Comment: @AndrewGustar, please post as answer? User could further use `assign()` to create the variables, but it's probably better for their workflow in the long run if they keep the results as a list ...

Comment: @AndrewGustar This works for me. However, it provides the list of vectors. I guess, I can unlist, or do we have any other options?

Comment: You could `attach()` the list. In the long run, you are likely to be **much** better off holding 17 categories in a list rather than generating 17 new vectors in your workspace ...

Comment: @Samarth I have updated my answer to show how to create separate variables (although working with a list is usually the better way to go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with...

```
split(df$Item, df$Category)

$Fruit
[1] "Apple"  "Grapes" "Orange" "Peach" 

$Vegetable
[1] "Onion"   "Potato"  "Cabbage"
```

Each vector becomes an element of a list.

If you really want to create a separate variable for each vector, you could do this (although it is usually easier to work with lists)...

```
split_df <- split(df$Item, df$Category)

mapply(function(x, y) assign(x, y, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
       names(split_df), split_df)
```

This will produce two new variables in the global environment called `Fruit` and `Vegetable`

Comment: Thank you @Andrew both of them works. As you mentioned that it would be easy to work with list. However, I need to add vector as an input for sapply. Is there any way to use list of vectors as an input for sapply? This would be super useful as I will create "list of list of dataframes" for further analysis. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, all of the `apply` family take lists as inputs. You can also nest them, like `sapply(df_list, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) {...}))` if you have a list of lists.

Comment: Awesome. This works very well for my case. Thank you so much @Andrew